# How to remove footer on datatables print

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and TableTools 2.2.4 and this is the code lines I use to initialize datatables with multi-filter inputs and the flash export buttons.

The problem is that I've been looking for the option to remove the footer of my table when user clicks on print button,  because the footer is the section where are each filter input elements so I don't want to let see those inputs to customers.

I've tried to use the

```
'sExtends':'print','bFooter':false
```

but it doesn't work on print button, only with rest of the buttons it works.

`tbl_consultarEmpleados` is the id of my table.

And do you know how to print the table automatically. I mean, when I click on print button it sends me to a preview so I want it to send me to the direct print action like in [this example](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/customisation.html).

```
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            //from here I start the datatables with multi filter options
            $('#tbl_consultarEmpleados tfoot th').each( function () {
                var title = $('#tbl_consultarEmpleados thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
                $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Filtrar" />' );
            } );
            var table = $('#tbl_consultarEmpleados').DataTable();

            table.columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;

                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );// from here I start the flash buttoms section
        var table= $('#tbl_consultarEmpleados').dataTable();

        var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table, 
        {
            'sSwfPath': '//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf',
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            'aButtons': ['csv','pdf',
            {
                'sExtends':'print','bShowAll':false,'sButtonText':'Imprimir','autoPrint': true
            },

            {
                'sExtends':'xls','sFileName':'*.xls','sButtonText':'Enviar a Excel'
            },

            ],

        });

        $(tableTools.fnContainer()).insertBefore('#tbl_consultarEmpleados_wrapper')

    } );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### CAUSE

According to the [TableTools - Button options](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options) `bFooter` option affects export buttons only.

#### SOLUTION

With the new [Buttons](http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) extension that replaced retired [TableTools](http://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/) you can remove footer as shown below. Auto-printing is enabled by default.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
       {
           extend: 'print',
           footer: false
       }        
    ]      
} );
```

See built-in [`print`](http://datatables.net/reference/button/print) button for more information.

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nn69fhqs/115/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Ok. It's good to know this new way, but although that works, I tried to use the rest of the buttons, but those doesn't work. I've tried some like this


dom: 'Bfrtip',
           buttons: 
           [
           {
            extend: 'pdf',
           },
              {
                  extend: 'print',footer: false,exportOptions: 
                   {
                    modifier: 
                    {
                        page: 'current'
                    },
                       stripHtml: false
                   } 
              } 

           ]

Comment: and two buttons appear, but the first ('pdf') has no title and doesn't any function

Comment: @MiguelAmaya, For other buttons to function, you need to include appropriate libraries, use [Download Builder](http://datatables.net/download/index). See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gr5er1pj/3/). I would recommend to avoid Flash as it proves to be vulnerable and some users choose to block it, see [this post](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/new-adobe-flash-zero-day-used-in-pawn-storm-campaign/) about recent vulnerability.

Comment: Actually, I was looking those libriries, so It works perfectly, thanks for your help.